# Filling boxplots with Texture or mixed colors

Tags: r, colors, textures, boxplot

I have a List() in which each element is a vector of values.
I created a vector of colors with the same length of the list, but I would like that one of the boxplot have a texture rather a single color.
I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913276/texture-in-barplot-for-7-bars-in-r), but it doesn't address my concern, I was hoping to find something like col="texture" instead of col="white", in order to combine it with the colors of the other boxplots

For example like this:

```
boxplot(My_list,col=c("white","red","blue","green","grey","pink","orange","lightblue","darkgreen","purple","yellow","brown","darkgrey"),ylim=c(-10,110))
```

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Some inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913276/texture-in-barplot-for-7-bars-in-r

Comment: Thank you, I already saw that, If i had a single boxplot to plot I'd know how to do it.
But in a series of boxplot I was hoping to find something like col="texture" , in order to combine it with the colorìs of other boxplots...

Comment: Tell it in the question, then.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help