# matplotlib bar plot fill with black texture

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to fill black texture to distinguish bars not use color in matplotlib?
I can't find any example.
just like this [texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913276/texture-in-barplot-for-7-bars-in-r) in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `matplotlib.pyploy.bar`object has the property `hatch`, which controls the kind of thing you are after.

Check out the doc for more info
https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

There is a really nice example of this in the matplotlib docs. 
https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hatch_demo.html

You may need to tweak the example to match your specific neads though.