# Calendar Heatmap: Colors not as specified

Tags: r, heatmap, levelplot

I'm using agstudy's modification of calendar heatmap ([discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014595/how-to-use-black-and-white-fill-patterns-instead-of-color-coding-on-calendar-hea/15027095#15027095) and source [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/agstudy/5024781))

In general, the code works very fine but I'm having trouble getting my color code to work. 
[image: Example]

In the example shown, the first 3 weeks should be colored red and the 4th blue. Altogether this sequence should repeat 6 times, i.e. there should be 6 weeks colored in blue (every 4th).

In order to achieve my color code I load a list of colors in hex code from a file and name it 'user':

```
col.sty <- switch(color,
'user'=data_2$colorMicro,
'r2b'=c("#0571B0", "#92C5DE", "#F7F7F7", "#F4A582", "#CA0020"), #red to blue                                                                               
'r2g'=c("#D61818", "#FFAE63", "#FFFFBD", "#B5E384")  , #red to green
'w2b'=c("#045A8D", "#2B8CBE", "#74A9CF", "#BDC9E1", "#F1EEF6"),   #white to blue
'b2w'=grey.colors(5) )## black to white
# assign("col.sty", get(color))
calendar.pal <- colorRampPalette((col.sty), space = "rgb")
```

The content of data_2 is:

```
colorMicro
#CC0000
#CC0000
#CC0000
#00CCFF
#CC0000
#CC0000
#CC0000
#00CCFF
#CC0000
#CC0000
#CC0000
#00CCFF
#CC0000
#CC0000
#CC0000
#00CCFF
#CC0000
#CC0000
#CC0000
#00CCFF
#CC0000
#CC0000
#CC0000
#00CCFF
```

These are 24 color values for the 24 weeks I want to represent in the heatmap. The variable `ncolors` is set to 24 and `cuts` is set to ncolors-1.

I've slightly changed my levelplot settings compared to the code from agstudy.

```
# major plot ------------------------------------------------------------------
 p <- levelplot(value~woty*dotw | yr, data=dat, border = "black",
            layout = c(1, nyr%%7),
            col.regions = calendar.pal(ncolors),
            aspect='iso',
            between = list(x=0, y=c(1,1)),
            strip=TRUE,
            main =varname, 
            panel = function(x,y,z,...) {
              panel.levelplot(x,y,z,...)
              ll <- list(...)
              at = pretty(dat$pvalue)
              ind.pch <- cut(dat$pvalue, at, include.lowest = TRUE, labels = FALSE)
              pch.symbols <- pch.symbol[ind.pch]
              subscripts <- ll$subscripts
              x <- x[subscripts]
              y <- y[subscripts]
              pch.symbols <-  pch.symbols[subscripts]
              a=ifelse(dat$pvalue==0,15,ifelse(dat$pvalue==1,16,ifelse(dat$pvalue==2,17,ifelse(dat$pvalue==3,18,ifelse(dat$pvalue==4,25,ifelse(dat$pvalue==5,10,ifelse(dat$pvalue==6,65,ifelse(dat$pvalue==7,66,ifelse(dat$pvalue==67,S,NA)))))))))
              b=ifelse(dat$pvalue==0,"blue1",ifelse(dat$pvalue==1,"darkorange4",ifelse(dat$pvalue==2,"red",ifelse(dat$pvalue==3,"seashell4",ifelse(dat$pvalue==4,"magenta",ifelse(dat$pvalue==5,"limegreen",ifelse(dat$pvalue>5,'yellow','black')))))))
              panel.xyplot(x, y,fill =col.symbol ,col.symbol =b,
                           pch = a, cex=cex.symbol,
                           ,  ...)
              calendar.division(...)  
            },
            scales= scales,
            cuts = ncolors-1,
            colorkey= list(at=seq(from=1, to=24, by=1), col = calendar.pal(ncolors), width = 0.6, height = 0.5),
            xlim =extendrange(dat$woty,f=0.01),
            xlab="",ylab="",
            ylim=extendrange(dat$dotw,f=0.1),
            subscripts=TRUE,
            par.settings = calendar.theme)
  p
}
```

I can't find out why the colors are shifted and don't match the intended color code. Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason?

Comment: I haven't used this packaged but I'm the author of https://github.com/Ather-Energy/ggTimeSeries which has another calendar heat map that you could use.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Because I also need symbols in the heatmap I'd prefer a solution for the current problem instead of using a different heatmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found out how it works:

In my **first try** I assigned the days of each week an individual number in ascending order from 1 to 24. I.e. the values of the days of week one were set to 1, the days of week two to 2 and so on. The list `colorMicro` contained 24 colors that were supposed to correspond to the individual weeks. The list contained colors multiple times.

In my **second try** I assigned all days with the same color the same number. At the same time I put the corresponding colors in the list `colorMicro`. This way each color appears only once in the list and in the same order as the numbers appear in the calendar. The variable `ncolors` I set to a large number and now everything works as desired.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V99sn.png)

The first way was easier for me in view of the data generation outside of R but for some reason it doesn't work. 
Knowing this fact, the second way is easy as well and leads to proper plotting behavior. Now it's possible to assign predefined colors to each day or week at free will, which is what I need. Maybe this is useful for others too.